# css element attribute class selection combo

Tags: css, html

I'm building a simple html5 range slider but depending on the context of the page I need the slider track to be red or white gradient.

```
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 105px;
  height: 8.4px;
  border-radius: 1.3px; 
}
```

I have two css classes .red_slider and .white_slider that will have a background property of *background: linear-gradient(left, black, [red|white]);*

How would I achieve this?

Comment: There are some good [examples on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/).

Comment: That's what I followed to get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
input[type=range].red_slider::-moz-range-track
```

work?